# presentModalViewController not responding from NSObject class

Tags: iphone

I have to need to call a presentModalViewController from NSObject class.

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        controller.delegate = self;
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [[appDelegate navigationController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
```

Above code is working fine for iPhone but not responding for iPad View.

Comment: Your app delegate's `navigationController` is probably `nil` for the ipad then - are you using a different view controller layout for the iPad? What is different between the iPhone and iPad versions? Only a view controller can present a modal view controller.

Comment: appdeligate or the navigation controller are not getting nil, problem is something else

Answer (score 0):

may be your appdeligate or the navigation controller are getting nil,
check your appdelegate declaration once or use the line

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] navigationController] presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Comment: appdeligate or the navigation controller are not getting nil, problem is something else